# Does USQL playback option is limited to edition of visual studio?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-data-lake

Visual Studio : 2015 Community Edition

Does playback option is limited to edition of visual studio.
or it is enabled only while processing job for source data located or output to azure data lake but  not to files located/output locally using usql?

**Files Used for Processing or Output are local path**
[image: Files Used for Processing or Output are local path]

**Job playback option and Output file exploration not working**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job execution playback is not supported with local execution.   There are implementation differences between local execution and cluster execution.

Thanks,

Yu Dong